# Offline-Online synchronization in Xamarin using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, mobile-application

I have done a lot of research however; I cannot find how to synchronize the data from Firebase Realtime Database in Xamarin. Is there any solution on how to synchronize for example if the user is offline and he/she wants to submit a data to the internet then by the time the user is online, the data will be stored and also the other user will fetch the data when they are online. Moreover, the other user should see the data even if the user is offline because in my case when the user is offline, the data is blank or the program closes.

I tried the documentation but I could not follow where to put the codes. On the other hand, I cannot get the `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` I think I'm missing something that I could not figure out. Moreover, I tried on YouTube but I could not find any solution out there.

Comment: Does any of your Firebase code work?

Comment: @Jason CRUD functions are okay but I need it to work while the internet connection (WiFi or Mobile Data) is off. For example, if the user is offline, the user would still see the data from the database and if the user is offline and want to add data, the user can submit the data and will be stored initially offline until the user gets online and then the stored data will then be saved to the server and will reflect to the other users.

Comment: You can refer to this case about [How do I to use RealTime Firebase offline in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128604/how-do-i-to-use-realtime-firebase-offline-in-xamarin).

Comment: @Liyun I tried it before but it does not work for me either.

Comment: Did you mean the official sample didn't work?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT
  No. What I mean is I have different kind of code method and I don't know how to substitute my code to the official sample.
<br/>
My data store in impelementations look like this:

<code>
```Task<bool> AddorUpdateAnswer(AnswerModel answerModel);
        </br>Task<bool> AddorUpdateNotCorrectAnswer(AnswerModel answerModel);
        Task<bool> DeleteAnswer(string key);
        Task<List<AnswerModel>> GetAllAnswer();```</code>